# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot destructure property 'setUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, token

I'm trying to set the user token once a user has logged in using createContext and useContext. Below are is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import FormErrors from '../../components/formErrors/formErrors';
import Button from '../../components/button/button'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function () {
    const AppContext = createContext();

    const history = useHistory();
    const {setUser} = useContext(AppContext);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState( '' );
    const [password, setPassword] = useState( '' );
    const [errors, setErrors] =  useState( [] );

    const onSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setErrors( [] );
        let _errors = []

        if (!email) _errors.push('Email is required');
        if (!password) _errors.push('Password is required');

        if(_errors.length) return setErrors(_errors);

        try {
            const data = {
                email,
                password
            };

            const response = await axios.post('/api/user/login', data);
            setUser(response.data.user);
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
            history.push('/');
        } catch (e) {
            setErrors([e.response.data.message]);
        }
        
    };

    return (
        <div className="page">
            <h1 className="page__title">
                Login
            </h1>

            <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form">
                {!!errors.length && <FormErrors errors={errors} />}
                <div className="form__group">
                    <label className="form__label">
                        Email 
                    </label>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type="text"
                    className="form__input form__group"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="johndoe@mail.com"/>
                </div>
                <div className="form__group">
                    <label className="form__label">
                        Password 
                    </label>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type="password"
                    className="form__input form__group"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Password..."/>
                </div>

                <Button type="submit">Login</Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm not able to destructure property 'setUser' in useContex. I get error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot destructure property 'setUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined." Any help please. It would be very helpful if you can give some good explanation too with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`const AppContext = createContext();` needs to occur *outside* the component, and the component needs to be wrapped in a provider that provides *that* context.

## Solution

App context

```
export const AppContext = createContext({
  setUser: () => {},
});
```

App

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState();

...

return (
  <AppContext.Provider value={{ setUser }}> // <-- wrap app with provider can value
    <App />
  </AppContext>
);
```

The above component

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
...
import { AppContext } from '../path/to/AppContext'; // <-- import context

export default function () {
  ...
  const {setUser} = useContext(AppContext); // <-- destructure should work now
  ...

  return (
    <div className="page">
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```